# Trying to prevent this function from firing till text box is "focusout" or something better

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I would like to get this function to check the email text box after the textbox has lost focus and not as soon as the user starts to type. So it only guides them after an error in the text box happens on .emailError textbox class.

I really don't want it to start showing error class till after the first try. Only to show green when the correct input has taken place.

```
var c = 0;
c = parseInt("c");

$('.emailError').on('focusout', function() {
    c = 1;
});

if (c == 1) { 
    $('.emailError').on('keyup focusout', function() {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
        var containsNonEmail = this.value.match(regex);
        console.log(containsNonEmail);

        if (!containsNonEmail) {
            $(".wirelessEmail").css("border", "2px solid #ffeef6");
            $(".wirelessEmail").css("background-color", "#ffecf2");
        } else {
            $(".wirelessEmail").css("border", "2px solid green");
            $(".wirelessEmail").css("background-color", "#f5fef2");
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: `var c = 0; c = parseInt("c");` I'm not sure what you're expecting that to do, but I can tell you it's not right.

Comment: use the onblur() function .. onblur is when you have moved out of the text box ...

Comment: I would like to change c = 1 when the user leaves the textbox, then in the if statment check to see if c is equal to 1 and if it is then run the email checking code on the textbox to do error control.

Comment: But why are you using parseInt?  It's already an int.

Comment: I was changing the var c to an int for my check as value of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the if else check inside of the function and not on the outside. When it is outside, you will not bind the event.

Better way would be to do the checking so you do not rely on a global variable, this way you could use it more than once on the page. To do that use a data attribute.

```js
$('.emailError').on('keyup focusout', function(evt) {
    var tb = $(this);
    var once = tb.data("once");
    if(evt.type==="focusout" || once) { 
         if (!once) tb.data("once", "true");
         var isError = tb.val().length<5;
         tb.toggleClass("error", isError);
    }

})
```

```css
.error { background-color : red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="emailError" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Onblur** function

The onblur event occurs when an object loses focus.

The onblur event is most often used with form validation code (e.g. when the user leaves a form field).

Comment: I am still unsure of how to get it to only fire only on the second try.

Comment: do you mean on the  second key hit .. as in  a b -> execute validation ??